# Git merge changes between upstream brnches

Tags: git, github, merge

I am a bit unsure how I can make changes to an upstream branch. I had a local copy of branch `A`, which had certain commits and is pushed to origin (my fork). Now I want to update branch `A` on original, and then later merge changes from branch `A` to branch `B` on upstream.

FYI, I already have changes on upstream branch `A`. I want to write those new changes on top of branch b on upstream.

Comment: If you forked the repository do you have access write on it? What do you mean `update branch A on original`.  Is original the repo you forked from?

Comment: Does `original` here mean the `upstream` repo or the `origin` repo (your fork)?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not entirely clear to me so I am just going to assume some things. So I assume you want to merge commits from branch **A** of your **local** repo to branch **B** of the **upstream** repo. I assume the fork and the upstream repos reside on GitHub (because it is tagged GitHub).

There are many ways to do this, depending on whether you have write access on the upstream repo. The recommended methods for merging on a shared repo are the 2nd and the 3rd ones (using [Pull Request](https://help.github.com/articles/using-pull-requests/) workflow)

#### If you have write access to the upstream repo

1. In your **local** repo, set the **upstream** repo as one of your remote repo, if you haven't already (you can name it whatever you want, but usually people will name it **upstream**). The command is

   `git remote add upstream <url/path of your upstream repo>`
2. Fetch the branch **B** from upstream by executing (both, in sequence)

   `git fetch upstream`

   `git checkout upstream/B`

   OR (if you already have a local copy of B)

   `git checkout B`

   `git pull upstream`
3. Merge B with A
4. While you are at branch B, execute `git push upstream B`

*NOTE* that merging to other people's branch locally and pushing it to a shared remote repo is considered a **bad** practice as the owner of the branch may not realize his/her remote branch is modified, which may result in branch divergence and unnecessary  merges.

#### If you DON'T have write access to the upstream repo

This is the method usually used by most people regardless of whether they have write access to the upstream repo or not. I.e. usually people don't push to upstream straight away unless under special circumstances, despite having write access.

1. Push branch **A** to origin (your fork)
2. Go to the **upstream** repo on GitHub and submit a [Pull Request](https://help.github.com/articles/using-pull-requests/). (Note which branches to *pull request from* and *merge into*)
3. Wait for the owner/collaborator of the remote repo to accept your Pull Request.

#### Yet another alternative

I noticed that you mentioned that you already have your changes on branch A on the upstream repo. In that case you can just do the **pull request** straight away. And if you have write access to the repo, you can accept your own Pull Request straight away. Again, this is a **bad** practice on shared repo, especially if branch B is not owned by you, or is a shared branch.

Hope it helps.